# OCR directly to text files Acrobat X

Tags: adobe-acrobat

In Acrobat 9, it was possible to export directly to text files when performing OCR on PDF documents, using the "Export to Alternate Format - Text" option. This feature appears to be missing in Acrobat 10. Is this still possible in a single step?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you'd need to go through "Save As". (I think after OCRing)

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible. After doing OCR go to File → Save AS → More Option

I usually start with `Text (Plain)` but if it doesn't work I try `Text (Accessible)` and if both don't work, I go with `Html Web Page`. The HTML requires a bit of clean up to get a well formatted text, but sometimes the OCR is not recognized by the `Save As Text`.

If none of the above render the text with typos, simply try selecting the text and copying it : it's not handy but it could take less time than to correcting the error made by the `Save As.`